# Compile Android telephony from framework source

Tags: android, android-ndk, telephony, telephonymanager

I want to compile android telephony API from the source for my research project, here is the link to Git:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/
```

The repo contain an Android.mk file and full of java codes, how can I compile it? I tried `ndk-build` command but I got the following warning:

```
Android NDK: WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You do not use Android Studio. You [follow the instructions for downloading and building the entire OS](http://source.android.com/source/requirements.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare should add that as an actual answer so it's more discoverable and can be chosen as the correct answer